# How to combine IEnumerable<string[]>

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to work on improving my LINQ skills, while at the same time beginning with Code Kata. Right now, I'm trying to improve my work on [this Kata](http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/) by using LINQ instead of foreach loops.

The requirements:

Have a method that will split a string on new lines (`'\n'`) into separate strings, and then split each of those on commas to a max of two numbers each.

Here's what I have so far:

```
private int Add(string numbers) {
    var arrays = numbers.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var list = arrays.Select(s => s.Split(new char[] { ',', }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

    // Additional code here...
}
```

As it stands right now, `list` is an `IEnumerable<string[]>`. I have been looking through the various LINQ methods (`Join()`, `Aggregate()`, etc), but haven't found anything that returns `IEnumerable<string>`. I'm starting to think that I'll need to write an extension method for that, but was hoping to see if there was an alternative I was missing.

**EDIT**

My end goal with this is to wind up with an `IEnumerable<int>`, though I was thinking I'd have to make a stop at an `IEnumerable<string>` before that point. If that can be combined into one step, that'd be even better.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you want to return?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I added an Edit to clarify what I'm looking for (`IEnumerabe<int>` as my final, but at least `IEnumerable<string>` in between)

Comment: Ok, But what should it contain?

Comment: Middle step (for my knowledge base) is the strings from the array split accordingly. At the end, each of those strings should be converted to an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `SelectMany`, you can do that in one statement like:

```
IEnumerable<string> result = 
    numbers.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .Select(r=> r.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
           .SelectMany(r=>r);
```

If you need parsed `int` values then you can use `int.TryParse` on each string value like:

```
string numbers = "1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9";
int temp;
IEnumerable<int> parsedNumbers =
                numbers.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(r => r.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                .SelectMany(r => r)
                .Select(r => { return int.TryParse(r, out temp) ? temp : int.MinValue; });
```

`int.TryParse` would fail for invalid values and in that particular case you can return any value indicating an error like `int.MinValue`

EDIT:

You can also do:

```
string numbers = "1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9";
IEnumerable<int> parsedNumbers =
    numbers.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
           .SelectMany(r => r.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
           .Select(int.Parse);
```

That will throw an exception in case of any invalid value.

Comment: Note that you can use `SelectMany` instead of the first `Select`, removing the need for the `SelectMany(r => r)`. I'd personally avoid declaring the `temp` variable outside a lambda expression, too... for example, it means that can't be parallelized safely. (It's not as functional, basically.)

Answer (score 7):

Fortunately it's really simple - you just want [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which acts as a "flatten" operation:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = list.SelectMany(x => x);
```

Or avoid `Select` to start with, and go straight to `SelectMany`:

```
IEnumerable<string> list = arrays.SelectMany(s => s.Split(new char[] { ',', }, 
                                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

(Obviously you can use `var` for both of these - I've only included the type for clarity.)

And as Habib has mentioned, you don't even need the intermediate `arrays` variable:

```
IEnumerable<string> list =
     numbers.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .SelectMany(s => s.Split(new char[] { ',' }, 
                                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

And to get an `IEnumerable<int>`:

```
IEnumerable<int> list =
     numbers.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .SelectMany(s => s.Split(new char[] { ',' }, 
                                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            .Select(s => int.Parse(s));
```

This will throw an exception (lazily) if any of the strings can't be parsed as an integer.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I added a clarification for my end game to my question. Getting from the `IEnumerable<string[]>` to `IEnumerable<string>` is one step that I needed to figure out, though not necessarily for this problem, it's something I needed to discover in general. For this problem, I eventually need an `IEnumerable<int>`, so I can chain another `Select()` and do the conversion in there, correct?

Comment: @krillgar: Yes, absolutely. I'll add that as another step.

Comment: I was doing some additional testing than what the link was asking for, and found a "bug" in this. If I call this method with a string of `"1, ,2"`, then that empty item does not get removed during the SelectMany.

Comment: @krillgar: That wasn't part of the requirements in the question. You can easily add a `Where` clause to remove any just-whitespace entries though.

Comment: I know it wasn't. I guess I might be breaking SO "rules" by continuing to ask additional questions on it. The red flag for me was that it wasn't removed in the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`.

Comment: @krillgar: Because it's not empty - it's a single space. But yes, I think at this point if you've got any more questions, it would be worth asking them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use `arrays.Select()` use `arrays.SelectMany()` which should return you an string array, rather than an enumeration of string arrays.

Comment: Well, it will return an `IEnumerable<string>` - not a string array.

Answer (score 0):

Yaay LINQ time! I was just re-reading Jon Skeet Edulinq SelectMany section.

This task is not too good for LINQ because you need control over the code and you have specific cases. Either way I would use some kind of decent tokenizer that's more safer and has better error handling. This is not the case to fire up LINQ for one-liners.

Ps, you can get away with SelectMany statement.

```
int sum = numbers
    .Split(new[] {"\r\n", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] {','}), 
                   (line, number) => int.Parse(number))
    .Sum();
```